# Expand Collpase Row In FlexGrid VB6

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

How to have **FlexGrid** in **vb6**, in Which we can **expand** and **collapse row**, if it is possible in vb6 FlexGrid then please tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

MSFlexGrid does not support expand & collapse row. The Hierarchical Flex Grid (MSHFlexGrid) does. This works quite well with SQL Server using MSDataShape provider but you don't say where you're getting your data from so you could try these to get you started...

http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/VB_Beginner/324737/324737/mshflexgrid/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228851%28v=vs.60%29.aspx